# How to set static IP address for android web app?

Tags: java, android, web-services, rest, web

I am developing Android application. I have connected my application to restful web Services. Whenever I connect my net that time my IP address are changed. So i want to set static IP address. But i have tried to static IP address via network Sharing properties. But it does not work. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Making question in **BOLD** font doesn't really help to get answer.

Comment: This question is off-topic because its related to networking and doesn't directly relate with programming.

Comment: @Log1c just edited :)

Comment: @user3543997, your internet-provider will give you always dynamic IP address. For static IP address for `internet` costs more than normal subscription cost as of my knowledge. you can look at [this](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/static-ip-address-advantages-disadvantages/) for more information of static ip address.

Answer (score 0):

You may try like codes :

```
public static final String URLPREFIX = "http://url/api";
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(URLPREFIX + "/method_name/token/"
                + mAuthKey);
        Log.e(TAG, "" + URLPREFIX + "/method_name/token/" + mAuthKey);
        try {

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            String jsonResponse = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            Log.e(TAG, "entity: " + jsonResponse);

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("collection");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject mFirstChild = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                int mId = Integer.parseInt(mFirstChild.getString("id"));
                String mTitle = mFirstChild.getString("title");
                arrayList.add(new CustomClass(mId, mTitle));

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```